# Android surfaceview/canvas flickering after sleep in thread

Tags: android, surfaceview

This is my first post here. Sorry if it is not well done and thanks in advance.

There is something that is driven me crazy.

I try to draw something and show it slowly on screen. For this I use Thread.sleep as shown in the code. But it is showing two different versions of the canvas in each iteration.

Can anybody explain what is wrong?

I only want to draw something and after a few seconds draw something else. And so on.

This is my code:

```
public class Vista extends SurfaceView implements Callback {
private Hilo hilo;
private SurfaceHolder sf;

class Hilo extends Thread {
    public boolean running;
    private Vista view;
    Canvas c = null;
    Bitmap btm = null;

    public Hilo(SurfaceHolder holder, Vista view) {
        sf = holder;
        btm = Bitmap.createBitmap(480, 800, Config.ARGB_8888);
        c = new Canvas(btm);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStyle(Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);

        int k = 0;
        while (running) {
            c = sf.lockCanvas();
            k+= 10;
            c.drawText(String.valueOf(k/10), k, 20, paint);
            sf.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);

          try {
              sleep(1000);
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }
    }
}

public Vista(Context context) {
    super(context);
    SurfaceHolder holder = getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(this);
    hilo = new Hilo(holder, this);
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    hilo.running = true;
    hilo.start();
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    boolean retry = true;
    hilo.running = false;
    while (retry) {
        try {
            hilo.join();
            retry = false;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your code is `sleep()`ing the Main thread, also known as the UI thread. This is something you absolutely mustn't do, as the main thread is responsible for handling all "stuff" in Android: UI rendering, UI event dispatch, etcetera. You can read the [Processes and Threads](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html) guide on the Android Developer website for more information. Choice quote:

> Thus, there are simply two rules to Android's single thread model:
>
> 1. Do not block the UI thread
> 2. Do not access the Android UI toolkit from outside the UI thread

The question then becomes, how *do* you animate a view without sleeping the main thread? The trick is to tell Android to go do something else and come back to you (redraw you) after a little while. Each time you draw, you calculate by how much to advance your animation.

One (crude) way to do this is with [`postInvalidateDelayed(long)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#postInvalidateDelayed%28long%29), which does exactly that: redraw your view after the given number of milliseconds. It's not a precise delay, it'll fluctuate a bit, so you can't assume that's exactly how much time passed. A way to do this is to store the `System.nanoTime()` in an instance field, so that the next time you're drawn, you can take the difference to a new reading of `nanoTime()`. This difference is how much time has passed and thus tells you by how much you should update your animation state. If your animation is supposed to last 1 second in total and 100 milliseconds went by since the last time you drew your scene, you must advance everything by 10%.

Android provides the [a lot of utilities](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/overview.html) to make this easier.